# Java app build fails with Mysql url pointing to a Docker Container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc

I have a Java App which needs to connect to MySQL.

On providing `url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<dbname>` I am able to build the Jar. I, however, want to run it on a Docker Container in a network where I also have a MySQL container with name `mysqlindocker` running. To build the Jar I put in URL as `jdbc:mysql://mysqlindocker:3306/<dbname>` which I hope would work on running inside the container. But I fail to do it because the build fails. My guess is that on my local machine Spring is not able to point to that db url.

How do I build a jar with URL as `jdbc:mysql://mysqlindocker:3306/<dbname>`?

P.S. I would not prefer pointing to MySQL running on localhost.

Comment: How are you building your jar? Do you have an entry in your hosts file pointing to the url refered by mysqlindocker? Try skipping the tests run when building the jar.

Comment: The question is a little bit unclear. Could you please add how do you run your docker container? (via docker run or docker-compose). Also please mention how do you run your spring boot?(using an IDE or also via docker).

Comment: I build the jar using `mvn clean install`. It fails on `@Test void contextLoads()`. If I comment that out, I am able to build the jar with db url point to my docker container.

To run mysql container I use `docker run -d --net=<network> --name=mysqlindocker mysql`

I run my app locally via maven commands, locally. In docker I run it using `docker run`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I build the jar using mvn clean install. It fails on @Test void
> contextLoads(). If I comment that out, I am able to build the jar with db url point to my > docker container

In the frame of unit tests executed during the `test` phase of maven, the `mysqlindocker` hostname cannot be resolved :

```
jdbc:mysql://mysqlindocker:3306/<dbname>
```

Only containers inside the same docker network will resolve that.
And as these tests are executed outside the container (before to start it to be exact), they cannot access that network.

How to solve that ?

1. Solving the root cause

In fact, the root cause of your build failure during the unit test execution is that you didn't define a jdbc url according to the target scope.
Indeed in the `test` phase of a maven build you generally want tests to use an in-memory database or a specific MySQL database. You don't want to use the same one than the which one used for the main application for consistent reasons (test reproducibility).
Here a good practice is using another db instance for unit testing and that db should be accessible from the host that runs the build (`localhost`).
You can overriding the `spring.datasource.url` property for executed tests : either by defining an `application-test.properties/yml` file in `src/test/resources` or overriding the property directly in the test class `@SpringBootTest(properties=...)`.

2. Workaround

Note that if the MySQL db container port is published on the host where the build is executed, a (temporary) workaround would be to keep localhost in the url defined in `spring.datasource.url` for the build and to override it with the docker container name at runtime when you run the JAR as container endpoint :

```
java -jar myApp.jar --my-prop-url=jdbc:mysql://mysqlindocker:3306/dbname
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. This is exactly what I wanted but wasn't sure of how to achieve.