# Unable to conect SpringBoot to MySql using Docker compose

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker, docker-compose

I have created a docker compose file, to connect MySql to a SpringBoot app. But i get this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:342) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2221) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2016) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
   at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
   at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
```

My Dockerfile, Ihave created a .jar file using Maven install:

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8083
ADD target/ProjectCrud.jar ProjectCrud.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "ProjectCrud.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
    services:
        docker-mysql:
            restart: always
            container_name: docker-mysql
            image: mysql
            environment:
                MYSQL_DATABASE: pfa
                MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: aze123qsd
                MYSQL_USER: root
                MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            volumes:
                - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            networks:
                - spring-db

            ports:
                - "3306:3306"
            healthcheck:
                test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=root --password=root--execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""
            interval: 2s
            timeout: 20s
            retries: 10


        sign-up-app:
            build: ./
            expose:
                - "10222"
            ports:
                - 10222:10222
            environment:
                WAIT_HOSTS: mysql:3306
            depends_on:
                - docker-mysql
            networks:
                - spring-db
  networks:
    spring-db:
```

My application.properties:

```
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=aze123qsd
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/pfa? 
    useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    server.port=8089
```

I tried to run my spring boot app in my local machine using docker default ip while runnig only MySql container in this docker-compose.yml file, and it worked perfectly. But when I try to docker compose the file. i get this error

Answer (score 0):

This probably is because the build of the Jar fails as the test for `contextLoads()` fails. I faced a similar issue. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60349532/java-app-build-fails-with-mysql-url-pointing-to-a-docker-container)

This probably is because the tests are running on your local and it cannot resolve `docker-mysql` as a reference. It can only be referenced by containers in the same network. You can fix this overriding test properties and make them use your localhost's database or an in memory database.

Try using this on the test class: `@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname"})`

Comment: Or as a workaround, you can ignore the test altogether, by marking it as ignored or commenting it all out.

Comment: But I'm using MySql as container from docker, I think this will provide an error.

Comment: That's the point. Even I am. The tests will run on your local when you build the jar using `mvn clean install`. It won't be able to point to your MySQL running on a docker container. Thus, override it to point to your local database.

Comment: If you don't have a local database installed or if you don't want that test to run, you can always disable that test, however not recommended.

Comment: Yes now I can create properlly my .jar file, but I still have the same error on docker.

Comment: Did you build the Docker image again after the new Jar was built?

Comment: Try these:

`docker build -f Dockerfile -t <appimagename> .`

Then create a network on which you got to run your app and mysql containers so that they can communicate.

`docker network create spring-mysql-network`

Comment: Run MySQL: `docker container run --name docker-mysql --network bowler-mysql-network -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD> -e MYSQL_DATABASE=<dbname> -d mysql:8`

Comment: Run the app: `docker container run --network bowler-mysql-network --name <appcontainernameofchoice> -p 8080:<SpringServerPort> -d <appimagename>`

Comment: I have tried all of them and still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and it is possible the database is not created before the main app starts. In my case I deleted the volume of database:

then run docker-compose up - main app should exit with code -1, after that mysql database should start its work,

wait for the database to be created,

stop app, by pressing ctrl+c, and finally run docker-compose up again.

After that all should work

Comment: Only thing that comes in my mind is to delete all `networks` from composer. Then it should use default network but this is .  And good idea mightt be to clear all images etc, and force to build it again. I use `docker system prune -a`